# Laravel query order by sum

Tags: laravel

Sorry for my bad English. I have table: `recent_posters`

I would like to show daily top 10 posters. Something I've tried:

```
RecentPosters::select('id', 'user', DB::raw('SUM(id) as daily_posts'))
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->orderByRaw('SUM(id) DESC')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

But this gives me array with same user, how can I show 10 different users? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show your table structure for recent_posters and daily_posts

Comment: @SaurabhMistry recent_posters: id | user | post_id  | created_at | updated_at. I do not have daily_posts, in future I will add where created_at >= Carbon::today()->subDay()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get today's top ten posts by different users :

```
    $today_top_10= RecentPosters::whereRaw('Date(created_at) = CURDATE()')
                                  ->distinct('user')
                                  ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
                                  ->take(10)
                                  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a timestamp in your DB. Maybe you can use it to order the posters by date added. And then set a limit of 10.

Comment: I have timestamp. Tried. Same.